# im trying to implement line count program in python with logic in c

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, dll, shared-libraries

im trying to implement file line count program in python with logic in c.I wrote the required C code and compiled it in Linux to produce a .so file and it is working smoothly as expected.

But when i compiled it in windows the resulted .dll file is not working as expected.(i downloaded my C compiler from Cygwin).

Heres my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int counter(char file_name[]);

int counter(char file_name[]){
char ch;
FILE *fp;
int l=0;
fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
{
    if ((ch) == '\n')
    {
        l=l+1;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
return l;
}
```

I compiled the above code to produce shared file(.so/.dll)

Below is my python code:

```
from ctypes import *

#load the shared object file
myp = CDLL('./myp.so')

res_counter=myp.counter

i=raw_input("Enter File Path: ")

res_counter.restype=c_int
out=res_counter(i)

print out
```

PFB th compiling in ubuntu

```
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/wctester/py2c$ ls
myp.c  myp.so  test2.py
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/wctester/py2c$ gcc -shared -o myp.so myp.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVAX8jf.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccVAX8jf.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/wctester/py2c$ gcc -shared -o myp.so -fPIC myp.c
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/wctester/py2c$ python test2.py
Enter File Path: ../bar
3
```

Here is my windows compilation(i changed myp.so to myp.dll in .py for windows)

```
[python2] C:\Users\Subbi Reddy\Desktop\py2c\py2c>ls
myp.c  test2.py  text.txt

[python2] C:\Users\Subbi Reddy\Desktop\py2c\py2c>gcc -shared -o myp.dll -fPIC my
p.c
myp.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 #include <stdio.h>
 ^

[python2] C:\Users\Subbi Reddy\Desktop\py2c\py2c>python test2.py
Enter File Path: text.txt

[python2] C:\Users\Subbi Reddy\Desktop\py2c\py2c>
```

The windows is not displaying the result(number of lines)

Comment: In what way is your program not working 'as intended'? You need to give examples of the input you are providing and the output you are getting.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: What does it display? Be specific. Is there an error message? Does it report a number which is wrong - too high, too low?

Comment: @barny it is not displaying any  result in windows...That is the problem if you see the output for linux it is displayong the result overe there( 3 is the number in this case)

Comment: is the file text.txt in the current directory?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be in the `ls` output you show above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103585/discussion-between-subbi-reddy-dwarampudi-and-barny).

Comment: I hope I'm not asking the obvious here, but for windows, you did import the dll not the .so right? It is not clear from your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code using mingw32-gcc(4.7.1). It works fine.

Edit:
I tried with cygwin too. It works there as well.

Comment: compiling is working for me... did it also posted the number of lines for you?(i.e the result)

Comment: @Subbireddydwarampudi yes. I did exactly the same steps and got number of lines.

Comment: i downloaded my gcc compiler from cygwin...but i am not sure whether im doing any thing wrong or it is issue with cygwin.

Comment: @Subbireddydwarampudi try mingw(easier would be installing codeblocks). For checking cygwin issue try using the dll from a c code.